# change navigationbar system barButtonItem color

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar, uiappearance

I want to create iOS 6 apps with iOS 7 style..

so far I can achieve it, the last problem is the NavigationBarItem the action button, the colour is white.

[image]

How I change the background and colour of the text is by add several line in AppDelegate.m

```
UIImage *backButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button_back.png"];
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:backButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:backButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                      [UIColor colorWithRed:(21/255.0) green:(125/255.0) blue:(251/255.0) alpha:1],
                                                      UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                                      [UIColor clearColor],
                                                      UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
                                                      [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, -1)],
                                                      UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,
                                                      [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:17.0],
                                                      UITextAttributeFont,
                                                      nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

the `button_back.png` is actually blank picture. I want to make the background is blank.

Comment: Maybe you'd better creating a subclass of UINavigationBar to do all what you want in it, and add it to all controllers you want to displays this navigationBar.

Comment: I think you have to replace the action system item with a bar button item that holds a blueish image. At least that's what I did yesterday. As far as I know there is no way to tint or recolor those system icons.